# How to limit size of uploaded file with LimitRequestBody and proxypass?

Tags: upload, apache-2.4

I want to generate a "Request Entity Too Large" error when users upload very big files on my server. With **mod-php**, this is simply:

```
<FilesMatch "^(upload|replace)$">
 LimitRequestBody 3000000
</FilesMatch>
```

With **php-fpm**, I tried"

```
<LocationMatch "^/(upload|replace)$">
 LimitRequestBody 3000000
</LocationMatch>
```

But, it didn't work. Next, I tried setting a proxy environment variable in `VirtualHost`:

```
SetEnv proxy-sendchunked
ProxyPassMatch ^/([^\.]+)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000${docroot}/$1
```

It didn't work too. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody "
Note: not applicable to proxy requests."

Comment: @c4f4t0r, they removed that note in [2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody).

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#request-bodies

The note there says:
LimitRequestBody only applies to request bodies that the server will spool to disk

Comment: might be a pretty big hammer to hit that nail with, but mod_security can do this with SecRequestBodyLimit.

Answer (score 2):

Following @rjewell's suggestion, you'll need to configure [mod_security](https://www.modsecurity.org/) on your apache proxy. Add the following directives to your VirtualHost that should be protected:

```
# Enable request processing
SecRuleEngine On
# enable inspection of request bodies
SecRequestBodyAccess On
# set actual request size limit
SecRequestBodyLimit 3000000
# actually generate an HTTP error, instead of truncating
SecRequestBodyLimitAction Reject
# Avoid big request bodies that do not try to upload files
SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit 1048576
# tune memory usage
SecRequestBodyInMemoryLimit 131072
```

You can read more on the directives in [mod_security's reference](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#SecRequestBodyLimit).

Depending on your use-case, consider the following points:

- Allocate more or less memory per upload request by changing the InMemoryLimit
- Allow larger non-upload requests with the NoFilesLimit